# Css3 parar depois de acabar a rotation?

Tags: css3, transform, transição

Eu estou a usar `transform: rotate(90deg)` para rodar uma `div` quando ponho o rato por cima. Uma vez que o retiro, ele volta à posição inicial. Existe forma de o parar?

Tenho o meu código assim

```
.openn{
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in; 
}
.openn:hover{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

<div class="openn">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x openn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize o jQuery para que o elemento `hover` não volte a sua originalidade quando o mouse sair de cima:

*Lendo alguns comentários, vamos para as edições!*

```
$('.openn').hover(function(){

   $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');

});
```

Lembrando que você deve incluir a biblioteca do jQuery para que isso funcione *(Caso ainda não esteja incluída)*.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

O `.hover()` é um evento capaz de combinar os eventos `mouseenter()` e `mouseleave()`, isso está escrito [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/hover/). *(O famoso dois coelhos numa cajadada só).* Isso nos facilita na escrita do código, e temos o poder de manipular os eventos da forma que quisermos. Um exemplo da manipulação dos dois eventos:

```js
$('.l').hover(function(){


 $(this).css('border-radius','50%');

},function(){

  $(this).css('background-color','white');
  $('body').css({'transform':'rotateY(-180deg)','background-color':'black'});
  
  
  
})
```

```css
.l{

  padding: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;

}

.openn{
   transition: transform 0.3s ease-in
 }


body{transition: 2s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='l'></div>
```

A vantagem de usar o `.hover()` é que podemos manipular qualquer elemento da página, sem a necessidade de declarar manualmente os dois eventos que fariam esse serviço. Ele é semelhante ao `:hover` do CSS mas infinitamente mais poderoso já que não ficamos preso a só um elemento e sua originalidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, para a melhorar, recomendaria que colocasse a `css` que tenha `transition: transform 0.3s ease-in` no `.openn` para obter melhor animação.

Comment: Para rodar *apenas o elemento em questão*, ao invés de rodar *todos os elementos* com a classe `.openn` de uma só vez, substitua o corpo da função por `$(this).css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');`, como comentado na resposta do @Guilherme Nascimento

Answer (score 10):

### Com Jquery

Usando assim, como na outra resposta vai fazer todos elementos que tem a classe `class="openn"` serem afetados, o que pode ser uma grande dor de cabeça:

```
$('.openn').hover(function(){
   // afeta TODOS os elementos com classe openn de uma vez
   $('.openn').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
});
```

Então use o `this`, **pois se tiver** mais de um elemento com a classe `.openn` todos elementos serão afetados ao invés de afetar somente o com `hover`.

```
$('.openn').hover(function(){
   // afeta somente o elemento que disparou o evento, não afetando os outros elementos com classe openn
   $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
});
```

Outro detalhe talvez seja preferível usar uma classe CSS com o nome `.hover` (não confundir com `:hover`), pois assim a animação CSS fica toda organizada dentro do CSS mesmo, ao invés de misturar com o JavaScript.

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.openn', function() {
   $(this).addClass("hover");
});
```

```css
.openn{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.openn.hover{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="openn">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x openn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="openn">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x openn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

### Com JavaScript puro

Importar jQuery somente para um efeito simples desse é totalmente desnecessário, se não usa jQuery, pode fazer simplesmente assim:

```js
function classOpenn() {
    this.classList.add("hover");
}

var openns = document.querySelectorAll('.openn');

for (var i = 0, j = openns.length; i < j; ++i) {
    openns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", classOpenn);
}
```

```css
.openn{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.openn.hover{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="openn">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x openn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="openn">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x openn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, apesar de ter sido mais desenvolvida, a resposta de @Bsalvo foi a que me ajudou.

Comment: @I_like_trains não é questão de mais desenvolvida, é a questão que apontei possiveis problemas e situações, como o do `this`, o que lhe apontei foi mais que detalhes, foi uma implementação mais "garantida". Entendeu? A escolha de melhor resposta é decisão sua, não quero te influenciar, apenas te ajudar, apontando que o código da outra resposta pode falhar em certos cenários

Comment: @I_like_trains editei a resposta, veja se ficou claro agora.

Comment: apesar de você ter comentado Guilherme, seu primeiro código ainda usa a classe ao invés do `$(this)`, mudando todos do mesmo modo.

Comment: @Dudaskank você testou no "Executar", será que você não passou o mouse rapidamente, acidentalmente por cima dos 2? Acho que houve alguma confusão.

Comment: Na verdade, o trecho não tem o "Executar", é aquele primeiro. Relendo, na verdade você diz para não fazer com 2x a classe `.openn` e colocou *como não deve fazer*, ao invés de colocar o trecho já com o `this`. Mais abaixo, você usa sim o `this`, mas numa versão já com outras alterações.

Comment: @Dudaskank a problema na minha interpretação de texto, entendi, estou melhorando o texto. Grato!

Comment: @Dudaskank corrigido, mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, boa, mas aproveitei e dei uma editada também na sua resposta, espero que não ache ruim rs

Comment: @Dudaskank ficou otimo, já aprovei! Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Embora a pergunta não mencione as tags `jquery` ou `javascript`, uma solução é detectar pelo jQuery quando a transição terminar e alterar o estilo do elemento:

**Usando jQuery:**

```js
$(".openn")
.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",
function(){
 $(this).css('transform','rotate(90deg)');
});
```

```css
.openn{
 transition: transform 0.5s ease-in; 
}
.openn:hover{
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="openn" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x openn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Perdoe-me, mas devo salientar que `99999999999s` é um baita de um remendo. PS: mova o `transition` pro seletor sem `hover`, creio que fique melhor.

Comment: "mas funciona" geralmente é parte da desculpa em situações aonde tem remendo, desculpe se soar grosseiro, mas é apenas minha visão técnica da situação. De qualquer forma, sendo ou não remendo, creio que funcionará melhor se colocar o transition no seletor `.openn {}` ao invés de `.openn:hover {}` ;) Até mais. PS: o downvote não é meu.

Comment: Um dos votos é meu, porque também considero ser gambiarra. Uma solução assim irá gastar recursos desnecessários do navegador *inifinitamente* ([veja aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdRxy.png)). Você não é obrigado a editar sua solução, nem excluí-la, muito menos mudar o jeito que você programa, os votos negativos são de pessoas que descordam do que fez e esse é o espírito da comunidade.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Blz, não tinha me atentado a isso.

Comment: Ah, agora sim, uma razoavel solução, fixar o efeito após a animação :D +1 (ps: isso consta que não fui eu quem lhe deu downvotes, pois eu voto só pela qualidade da postagem e não por picuinhas ;))

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Que bom.Eu tb não costumo dar DV nem quando vejo resposta esdrúxula (exceto alguns casos raros). Eu não gosto é da prepotência da resposta quando pretende ser uma grande resposta e não diz nada, ou diz muita coisa quando poderia dizer pouco. Do tipo encher linguiça. Tenho notado aqui que mts programadores experientes fazem respostas extensas pra dizer pouca coisa só pra chamar a atenção. Bom, isso não é errado, mas quem conhece percebe a malandragem. Não estou dizendo que é o seu caso, ao contrário, vejo mts respostas suas e tenho dado mt +1 nelas por serem ótimas.

Comment: @Dvd obrigado. Eu não sei que respostas se refere, mas existem 3 usuários que geralmente postam respostas bem grandes, não sei se se refere a algum deles, no entanto o que você pode presumir que é prepotencia pode ser algo que as vezes não dominamos para entender do que o autor esta falando, esses 3 usuários já receberam acusações similares a sua por parte de outros usuários, que diziam que eles poderiam fazer respostas menores, no entanto apesar de eu não dominar todos assuntos que eles falam, ao ler e pesquisar comecei a notar que muita coisa no texto se fazia sim necessário...

Comment: ... Então não podemos confundir respostas técnicas grandes que pode ter algo que não dominamos para entender a motivação com prepotência ou com qualquer outro tipo de atitude. Eu mesmo já li muitas perguntas do qual eu não domino nada, mas ao conversar com o autor da resposta (via chat) algumas vezes consegui um entendimento, do qual notei que o motivo de não entender o porque da resposta é porque eu não dominava de fato o assunto. Creio que isso seja algo valido pra qualquer participante do site. Mais uma vez obrigado e boa sorte.