# Como executar um callback quando uma animação CSS for encerrada?

Tags: javascript, css3, animação, callback

Eu vi que o [angular-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) consegue detectar quando uma transação CSS está em progresso ou não para aplicar determinadas ações.

Eu preciso descobrir como eles fazem isso!

Exemplo:

```css
#square{
   background-color: tomato;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   transition: background-color .2s linear, color 1s ease-out;
}


#square:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: tomato;

}
```

```html
<div id="square">
   SQUARE
</div>
```

Como se faz para detectar o fim de uma transição de uma animação em **Javascript Puro**?

<sub>Respostas com jQuery não são bem-vindas :D</sub>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Css3 parar depois de acabar a rotation?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249479/css3-parar-depois-de-acabar-a-rotation)

Comment: Não entendi a parte do "Respostas com jQuery não são bem-vindas :D" ainda que a pergunta seja sua, ela não é para o bem da comunidade? E se alguém estiver procurando uma solução para jQuery?

Comment: @Raizant fiz isso porque sempre tem um espertão que colocam respostas que não tem nada a ver com o que foi perguntado para ganhar ponto fácil. era bem capaz de alguém colocar um `fadeOut` kkkkkkkk

Answer (score 2):

O evento a se usar é o [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend), os

```js
let square = document.querySelector("#square");
square.addEventListener('transitionend', function (event) {
     console.log("Terminou:", event.propertyName);
});
```

```css
#square{
   background-color: tomato;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   transition: background-color .2s linear, color 1s ease-out;
}


#square:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: tomato;

}
```

```html
<div id="square">
   SQUARE
</div>
```

No entanto é importante notar que para cada efeito que será animado, no seu caso é `color` e `background-color` será disparado dois eventos `transitionend`.

Outra coisa muito importante de se notar, é que se você tirar o mouse de cima de elemento ele irá fazer a animação inversa, o que ainda é uma animação e portanto irá também disparar o evento, veja conforme o exemplo com tempos longos:

```js
let square = document.querySelector("#square");
square.addEventListener('transitionend', function (event) {
     console.log("Terminou:", event.propertyName);
});
```

```css
#square{
   background-color: tomato;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   transition: background-color 2s linear, color 3s ease-out;
}


#square:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: tomato;

}
```

```html
<div id="square">
   SQUARE
</div>
```

---

### O evento `transitioncancel`

Existe o evento `transitioncancel` que é capaz de checar se a animação/transição foi cancelada no meio do caminho

> Só funciona no Firefox 53+, outros navegadores **não tem suporte**

conforme exemplo:

```js
let square = document.querySelector("#square");
square.addEventListener('transitionend', function (event) {
     console.log("Terminou:", event.propertyName);
});
square.addEventListener('transitioncancel', function (event) {
     console.log("Cancelado:", event.propertyName);
});
```

```css
#square{
   background-color: tomato;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   transition: background-color 2s linear, color 3s ease-out;
}


#square:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: tomato;

}
```

```html
<div id="square">
   SQUARE
</div>
```

---

### Retro-compatibilidade

Para navegadores antigos o `transitionend` é somente suportado com prefixos, se necessita de retro-compatibilidade então pode usar os seguintes eventos:

- `.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd')`: antes do Chrome 36 e WebKit 7.0.6 (Safari e Android)
- `.addEventListener('oTransitionEnd')`: Implementado no Opera 10.5
- `.addEventListener('otransitionend')` (em minusculo): Implementado no Opera 12.0 (opera passou a suportar sem prefixo no 12.10)

Answer (score 1):

Pra você que só quer javascript cru:

```
// Determinando o elemento 
var e = document.getElementsByID('#square')[0];

// Checando o evento 
function checkTransicao(){
    var t;
    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
      'transition':'transitionend',
      'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition':'transitionend',
      'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }

    for(t in transitions){
        if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
};


// Criando o evento 
var transitEvent = checkTransicao();

transitEvent && e.addEventListener(transitEvent, function() {
    //aqui é o callback


});
```

Pra quem usa JQUERY:
Acredito que dê pra pegar sempre o fim da animação assim:

```
    $('#square').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
    function(e) {
    // execução do código pós término

  });
```

Ou você pode capturar o evento uma vez só assim:

```
    $('#square').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
    function(e) {
    // execução do código pós término

  });
```

Você escolhe... ;)

Comment: Coloca a fonte de onde você copiou o primeiro bloco de código, por favor.

Comment: `msTransitionEnd` não esta documentado em lugar algum, existem lugares que afirmam que o correto é `MSTransitionEnd`, mas também não esta documentado.